# Long runtime while performing merge into operation in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to validate records present in table.First, we load the records into table and then we validate it using sql query. I am using below query to update the status code but to process 114000, it took around 7 hours. Is it acceptable? I am not sure why it's taking too much time.Please suggest any better idea so that I can minimize the time.

Query :

```
MERGE INTO mem_src_extn t USING 
( 
SELECT mse.rowid row_id,
       CASE WHEN mse.type_value IS NULL OR mse."TYPE" IS NULL OR mse.VALUE_1 IS NULL or mse.VALUE_2 IS NULL THEN '100'
            WHEN ( SELECT count(*) FROM cmc_mem_src cms WHERE cms.tn_id = mse.type_value ) = 0 THEN '222'
            WHEN count(mse.value_1) over ( partition by type_value ) > 1 THEN '333'
       ELSE '000' int_value_1  
FROM   mem_src_extn mse
) u
ON ( t.rowid = u.row_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.int_value_1 = u.int_value_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance problem is probably caused by the `SELECT count(*)` subquery , not the `MERGE`.

The `MERGE` uses a `ROWID` join, which should be about as fast as any join can get.  But it's possible that Oracle is incorrectly optimizing the subquery.  Try re-writing the statement with a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a correlated subquery:

```
MERGE INTO mem_src_extn t USING 
( 
SELECT DISTINCT
       mse.rowid row_id,
       CASE WHEN mse.type_value IS NULL OR mse."TYPE" IS NULL OR mse.VALUE_1 IS NULL or mse.VALUE_2 IS NULL THEN '100'
            WHEN cms.tn_id IS NULL THEN '222'
            WHEN count(mse.value_1) over ( partition by type_value ) > 1 THEN '333'
       ELSE '000' END int_value_1
FROM   mem_src_extn mse
LEFT JOIN cmc_mem_src cms
       ON mse.type_value = cms.tn_id
) u
ON ( t.rowid = u.row_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.int_value_1 = u.int_value_1;
```

But this is only a guess.  If I'm wrong, the next step would be to get a query plan.  Run `explain plan for merge ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and post the entire output of that statement in the question.